# Floated elements have smaller width than the grid column

Tags: singularitygs

I am trying to do a Singularity layout with a main container and a sidebar. In the main container I'd like to have a list of floated elements that will get line breaks at each 3.

Here's the relevant gist:
http://sassbin.beta.caliper.pl/gist/8704970/

Unfortunately width(1) + width(2) + width(3) != width(main). What am I doing wrong? I have to use the grid for items 1..N, because they need to align elements in the page's header (not included in the gist).

Answer (score 0):

So after approaching the topic with a fresh mind I managed to get the expected positioning.

Here's a new gist for everyone to compare:
http://sassbin.beta.caliper.pl/gist/8900975/

There where a few things that needed changing:

1. Add `body { margin: 0 }` to align the `@include background-grid()` visualizations with the act.
2. Remove all borders and replace them with backgrounds to get rid of 1px differences.
3. Change grid inside item container with `@include layout()` to match the container's grid-span.
4. Style items with `nth-child` and @include `float-span()`.
5. Specify `last` for the last item in a row to avoid unexpected line breaks.

The crucial part of the code is:

```
#main {
  @include grid-span(9,1);
  background: yellow;

  @include layout(9) {
    .item {
        &:nth-child(3n+2) {
          @include float-span(3,1);
          background: blue;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+0) {
          @include float-span(3,1);
          background: red;
        }
        &:nth-child(3n+1) {
          @include float-span(3,last);
          background: green;
        }
    }
  }
}
```